# ASP.NET Visual Studio scaffold id parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, parameters

When I create an MVC project in Visual Studio, it scaffolds the controller for me.  In the Details, Edit, and Delete Actions, there is in "int? id" parameter in the Actions.

Where does this id come from? How does it know which id to look for? Does it just know it's looking for the primary key id pertained to that object?

Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Comment comment = db.Comments.Find(id);
        if (comment == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(comment);
    }
```

Comment: It scaffolds the controller via the Dialog questions you answer, AFAIK. You picked Controller with empty actions, which it provided. Yes, it knows its looking for a PK, and uses nullable int as its type. You can now fix it to fit your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I will try to explain. When you are creating some controller (not empty) it writes some deafault actions for you. Which are as follow.

Index- It shows the list of the data of your entity Model.
Create- It enables you create a new object (instance) and add it in the Entity Model.
Delete- It deletes an instance.
**Details**- If you want to see a detail of the instance this action is used. The parameter is "Id". So server fetch the exact instance depending on the Id (which is Primary Key) from the db. So how this action gets the Id? The Answer is: From the view. From the view you are requesting for detail view of a single instance by sending it's id. Does that make sense?  I will attach a grid picture in here.[Sample Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kM4L.png)

So from the grid if you look in the right, you can see a Pen Sign and a Page sign. The page sign is my detail button. So if I click on the page sign of the first row, I am sending the primary key of the instance whose first name is Rupa and requesting server to get the detail data of this instance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped a lot. Now I understand that it comes from the View...makes sense!

Comment: Absolutely my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when doing scaffolding to create controller with CRUD actions, MVC looking for default route in `RegisterRoutes` method like this:

```
public class RouteConfig 
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default", // Route name
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
}
```

From route definition above, `id` parameter is declared as optional, however during edit or delete operations, the controller required to know which data should be edited/deleted by supplying `id` parameter.

The reason behind `Nullable<int>` has been chosen to declare `id` parameter is to ensure checking against possible null value passed from view side (note that controller searches in database based on primary key value using `Comment comment = db.Comments.Find(id)`).